# Detect Xcode project development language

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

We can create a new Xcode project using Objective-C or Swift.

I want to detect, which language was selected when a project was created?

Projects can be a mix of Objective-C and Swift, but I am concerned about the language, selected during project creation.

May be it can be through pbxproj file or other better way.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Xcode projects change; could be created for Obj-C code initially and added Swift files afterwards.

Comment: @meaning-matters I am writing a tool which will add a given component(hosted somewhere) to the xcode project. So I want to detect the project dev language and add component according to its dev language.

Answer (score 3):

ObjC project always contains the entry point that is main function.
Usually it is inside main.m file but it is not  necessary. Developer can replace it to any name.
I tried 2 simple projects. One is in ObjC and second one is in Swift.
When I was tried to add new file the Xcode offered Swift language for Swift project and Obj-C for Obj-C project file.
Next I removed in Swift project AppDelegate.swift file and added AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m and (sic!) main.m files. of course I had to create bridging file for obj-c.
Which contains

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

I was able to compile this project but when I tried to add new file Xcode offered me to add Objective-C file. But initially the project was created as Swift project.

I did similar manipulation for Obj-C project.
I removed AppDelegate.h and .m file as well as main.m and added AppDelegate.swift
I was asked to create bridge file and did empty file.
Next I went to «Build Settings» and switched Define Module parameter to YES value. (Without this I got linker error).

After it I was able to build and run this initially obj-c project which has AppDelegate in Swift now. 
When I tried to add a new file the Xcode offered me to add new Obj-C file too.
So. It looks like you cannot detect initial language based on a parameter in Xcode because project can be always corrected. I think that rarely the developer will try to replace AppDelegate in a project and add\remove main entry point.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks! "ObjC project always contains the entry point that is main function." 